# How to add undo action to NSMenuItem programmatically?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

I'm building NSMenu programmatically without any Nib(s).
Please take a look at this code:

```
self.editMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit"];

[self.editMenu addItemWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Undo", nil)
                         action:@selector(undo:)
                  keyEquivalent:@"z"];

[self.editMenu addItemWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Redo", nil)
                         action:nil
                  keyEquivalent:@"Z"];

[self.editMenu addItem:[NSMenuItem separatorItem]];

[self.editMenu addItemWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cut", nil)
                         action:@selector(cut:)
                  keyEquivalent:@"x"];

[self.editMenu addItemWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Copy", nil)
                         action:@selector(copy:)
                  keyEquivalent:@"c"];

[self.editMenu addItemWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Paste", nil)
                         action:@selector(paste:)
                  keyEquivalent:@"v"];
```

As you can see there are `@selector(cut:)`, `@selector(copy:)` and `@selector(paste:)`. But there are no `@selector(undo:)` and `@selector(paste:)`. The compiler says "Undeclared selector 'undo:'.

[image: Undeclared selector undo:]

How can I implement undo and redo menu item's action programmatically?

Comment: Look up `NSUndoManager`

Comment: If you ignore the warning, does undo work?

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: Does your app support undo?

Comment: @Willeke I don't know how to make my app support undo and also to integrate it to undo menu action. That must be the reason why it didn't work.  Could you tell me how?

Comment: I don't know anything about your app. Read [Undo Architecture](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/UndoArchitecture.html).

Answer (score 0):

found a solution here(if still need) -

https://github.com/lapcat/Bonjeff/blob/master/source/MainMenu.swift

```
@objc protocol EditMenuActions {
    func redo(_ sender:AnyObject)
    func undo(_ sender:AnyObject)
}

menu.addItem(withTitle:title, action:#selector(EditMenuActions.undo(_:)), keyEquivalent:"z")
menu.addItem(withTitle:title, action:#selector(EditMenuActions.redo(_:)), keyEquivalent:"Z")
```